# Deleting remote files is better with file.delete() or making ProcessBuilder call with rm -rf?

Tags: java, file, delete-file, processbuilder, rm

If `file.delete()` is better, how is it? What are the problems of using ProcessBuilder? Also I have to loop through a list to delete the different files. In such a scenario, what is the best approach?

Comment: A new process per file is obviously vastly inferior to a single method call, but you don't get what the -f does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using java File.delete is better approach, since:

i) Java code will be portable across different OS, if used File.delete() instead of executing OS dependent commands on ProcessBuilder Api.
ii) A java programmer can easily understand the functionality written to delete list of different files.

Cons:

i) Since java doesn't allow delete a non-empty directory, we need to write a util method to recursively delete files in directory as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-directory-in-java/), unlike using ProcessBuilder Api, which removes the directory with single command **rm -rf**